# How many documents can MondoDB handle?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, limit

I've been making game replay system that saves player actions every 100ms as JSON file. Currently I'm using Java for it so I can convert json to map or text without delay. Average size of json is 8MB and maximum is 15MB. I used to upload json file to internet and whenever player wants to watch it again I downloaded from internet but it's bad for me. If you consider traffic and usage of internet is bad for me. So I've decided to use database and tried Redis but it's not one for this process. In the end of the day I've only one database remaining which is MongoDB.

**Questions**

1. Is 15MB per document bad for mongodb?
2. I often push and pull the 15MB data from mongodb. May it cause slowdown on average system?
   As an example 10 data push/pull every 10 minute.
3. After a while there'll be a lot of datas which are over 10MB each. May it be problem in future for me?
4. I'd like to use MongoDB timer for documents. I'll kill each documents after 48 hours. Is it bad idea to use MongoDB timer for each document?

**NOTE:** *Decidated server and Mongo server is in same location and machine. You can think of decidated server features like an average system.*

I'd like to get answers to my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is 15MB per document bad for mongodb?

No.

> I often push and pull the 15MB data from mongodb. May it cause slowdown on average system? As an example 10 data push/pull every 10 minute.

What is "system" referring to? The database server? The application server? The client using the application?

When the data is being transfered, it will utilize network bandwidth and there will be less bandwidth remaining for whatever other operations may be concurrently going on on any of the 3 possible "systems".

> After a while there'll be a lot of datas which are over 10MB each. May it be problem in future for me?

Assuming you can pay for storage and stay within [MongoDB limits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/), no.

> I'd like to use MongoDB timer for documents. I'll kill each documents after 48 hours. Is it bad idea to use MongoDB timer for each document?

No.

Answer (score 0):

It can store any number of document given size is Up to 16MB per document.
I recommend you to read this article https://www.mongodb.com/compare/mongodb-dynamodb
Your doubts might get clear.

Comment: As I mention it above I know the limitation on MongoDB but I'd like to know performance about it. You may check my question again.